# Why does indexing not work for linked data?

Tags: java, indexing

Could someone explain why “indexing” does not work for linked data.

Also a little more information about the way indexing works with arrays.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you meant by "Linked Data" in the context of your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You questions is vague but i'll try to answer it the best I can.

First, arrays:

This will be easiest to explain with an example:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Notice the array `array` has 6 values (i.e. the size is 6). This can be a bit confusing to new developers, because array indexing starts at 0. Therefore,

```
array[0] equals 1
array[1] equals 2
array[2] equals 3
.
.
.
array[5] equals 6
```

All in all, arrays indexing starts at value 0, and ends and value "arraySize - 1". You can access these value by simply using `array[index]`. This is polar opposite from linked-data which is presented below

Now onto "linked data". Once again i'll use an example to explain "indexing". This usually consists of a linked-list like below:

```
"1" -> "2" -> "3" -> "4" -> "5" -> "6"
```

Note: This is a singly linked list, meaning each node has only 1 link (which is the next node in the list).

"indexing" doesn't exist in the same way that it does for arrays because you aren't always passed the "head" or the linked-list, and because you can't simply access the value of "index 3" like you can with arrays.

Imagine if you were given list node `"3"`. How would you "index" this value? As a programmer all you know is that `"3" -> "4" -> "5" -> "6"`. You have no information about `"1" -> "2"`, therefore there is no way to know if node `"3"` is "index" 0, or "index" 2.

Does this answer your question?